# Number of paths in a rectangle from top left corner to bottom right corner

Tags: combinatorics

Given a rectangle of heigh $H$ and width $W$, a smaller rectangle of height $A$ and width $B$ is cut out from the *top-right* corner of the rectangle.
$H,W,A,B \subset I$. $I$ denotes the set of integers.

Assume this figure to be tiled evenly with squares of dimension $1X1$.

We are supposed to find the number of ways of going from the top-left corner of the figure to the right-bottom corner of the figure.

Some steps of my approach:

First I found the total number of ways to reach the bottom-right corner for the original rectangle, which is $C(H+W,H)$.

Now, I am unable to figure how exactly I must subtract the number of ways for the cut-out area from the number of ways for the original rectangle.

How do I find the total no. of required ways here?

[image: Image is just for illustration]

The image is just for a fair idea about how the figure looks like after cutting out the smaller rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you can only move down and right.

So label the inner corner, say $A_1 = (W-B,H-A)$, and count off $A_2 = (W-B-1,H-A-1)$, $A_3 = (W-B-2,H-A-2)$, until $A_k = (W-B-k, H-A-k)$, where $k = \min\{W-B,H-A\}$. Then, all your desired paths from top left corner $(0,H)$ to bottom right corner $(W,0)$ must pass through exactly one $A_i$ for some $i$. So, we want to count the number of paths from top left corner to $A_i$ and from $A_i$ to bottom right corner, multiply the two numbers (the product signifies the number of paths through $A_i$), and sum over $i$ to get the desired answer.

Comment: Let P(i) be no. of paths from left top to $A_i$ and Q(i) be no. of paths from $A_i$ to right corner.
Then is the answer sum of P(i)*Q(i) or is the answer C(h+w,h) - sum of P(i)*Q(i)?

Comment: You can find $P(i)$ and $Q(i)$ in terms of $i, W, H, A, B$ as you did above; use the same line of reasoning you did to get that the number of paths on the $W \times H$ rectangle is $\binom{W+H}{W}$. Then, the number of paths passing through $A_i$ is $P(i) \times Q(i)$.

Comment: Yes, I found that out.
However, consider a rectangle with $W=2, H=3$ and $A=2, B=1$. The number of ways should be 7, but sum P(i)*Q(i) gives 4.

Comment: In your example, there are $\binom{3}{2} \times \binom{2}{1} = 6$ paths through $(1,1)$ and $\binom{3}{0} \times \binom{2}{0} = 1$ path through $(0,0)$. Hence, 7 total paths.

Comment: Can you explain your $\binom{3}{2}$ term please?

Comment: "First I found the total number of ways to reach the bottom-right corner for the original rectangle, which is $C(H+W,H)$."

Comment: Suppose $A_i$ has coordinates $(a_x, a_y)$. Then, I have calculated no. of ways from top left = $\binom {a_x + a_y}{a_x}$ and no. of ways to bottom right = $\binom {W - a_x + H - a_y}{H - a_y}$.

Hence, for $(1,1)$, I am getting 6 paths, but for $(0,0)$ I am getting 10 paths.

Can you point out the mistake in my formula for P(i) and Q(i)?

Comment: Ok, I got my mistake :) Thanks a lot!